# regex to mark duplicated xml columns in nodepad++

Tags: regex, xml

i've got xml file with products:

```
<PRODUCTS>    
  <PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>product 1</PRODUCT_NAME>
    <KOD_PRODUCENT>GXP-579288</KOD_PRODUCENT>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>product 2</PRODUCT_NAME>
    <KOD_PRODUCENT>GXP-579775</KOD_PRODUCENT>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>product 3</PRODUCT_NAME>
    <KOD_PRODUCENT>GXP-579775</KOD_PRODUCENT>
  </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

and i have to mark KOD_PRODUCENT column if her value is duplicated (like product 2 and product 3). how to write regex to find duplicates in nodepad++?

Comment: The KOD_PRODUCENT always starts with `GXP-`?

Comment: no, sometimes its looks like <KOD_PRODUCENT>A119</KOD_PRODUCENT> or
<KOD_PRODUCENT>6496</KOD_PRODUCENT>

Comment: So what is the permanence?

Comment: and about the duplicates, do you want to know just if there are duplicates or to know what are the duplicates?

Comment: i need to know which codes are duplicated

Comment: First, is the regex in my answer good for your problem? second, you can group it by the kod - product, and find which has more then one. Third, What language do you use?

Comment: i'm working with xslt, i can group products by KOD_PRODUCENT and find duplicates but i'm looking for some more flexible solution because i have more xml files like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this regex to match the KOD_PRODUCENT:

```
<KOD_PRODUCENT>\K[^<>]+
```

[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8MV0ZD/1)

Then you have to check duplicates.

Good Luck!

Comment: this regex seems to mark all KOD_PRODUCENT not only duplicated

Comment: The regex is for find the Kod Products. After you find it, you can search for duplicates.